# How to tell Azure Table Storage to not store certain entity properties

Tags: azure, azure-storage, nosql

Given the following class

```
public class Account : TableEntity
{
    public Account()
    {

    }
    public Account(string customerName, string username)
    {
        PartitionKey = customerName;
        RowKey = username;
    }

    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public string CustomerName
    {
        get
        {
            return PartitionKey;
        }
        set
        {
            PartitionKey = value;
        }
    }

    public string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            return RowKey;
        }
        set
        {
            RowKey = value;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I added 2 properties that wrap the RowKey and PartitionKey for more readibility and convenience in my codebase. Problem is that these properties are also stored in my Table in Azure Storage, which is not what I want.

I tried using the NotMapped attribute, but that doesn't seem to be working for this scenario. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found it. The namescape

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table
```

contains an attribute that enables you to skip properties when saving entities to Table Storage. It's called

```
IgnorePropertyAttribute
```